# Запрос к трём таблицам

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart

Как правильно получить информацию из трёх разных таблиц?

У меня сейчас есть:

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_order_product WHERE order_id = 
(SELECT order_id FROM oc_order_product ORDER BY order_product_id DESC LIMIT 1)");
```

и

```
EOD;
for($i = 0; $i<count($result->rows); $i++) {
$points = $result->rows[$i]['points'];
$price = $result->rows[$i]['price'];
$counts = $result->rows[$i]['quantity'];
$str .= <<<EOD
```

А вот эти уже идут из другой таблицы, не из `oc_order_product`, а из `oc_product_option_value`:

```
$price = $result->rows[$i]['price'];
$counts = $result->rows[$i]['quantity'];
```

Как мне правильно добавить в `$result` из `oc_product_option_value` значения `price` и `quantity`?

Comment: 1. я вижу в вашем вопросе упоминания только двух таблиц: oc_order_product и oc_product_option_value. где же третья таблица? 2. насколько вижу, вы ни словом не упомянули, каким образом связаны между собой эти две таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте слияние таблиц JOIN, например:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.points, T2.price
FROM tbl1 AS T1
INNER JOIN tbl2 AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```

тем самым получите значения из нескольких таблиц. Какое слияние лучше использовать - это нужно почитать.

P.S. Кстати запрос ваш какой то странный. Зачем писать id_order = и еще раз вызывать по сути тот же запрос... достаточно только запрос из скобок

```
SELECT order_id FROM oc_order_product ORDER BY order_product_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: думаю в этой таблице записи по order_id не уникальны, так что это выборка всех записей с максимальным order_id, которая была бы гораздо короче как =(select max(order_id) from oc_order_product)

Comment: @Mike, вы абсолютно правы по поводу возможной неуникальности order_id, но, по-моему, не совсем правы по поводу «можно гораздо короче»: у автора вопроса выбирается максимальное значение столбца order_product_id, а не order_id.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Да, перепутал id